# How to make a contact form in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

//IT would be very helpful if when the user clicks submit the form is sent to webdyno5@gmail.com

```
<div id="contact-box">
            <form action="">
                <div class="form-group" id="name">

                    <label for="name">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="email">
                    <label for="email">Email: </label>
                    <input type="email" name="name" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="subject">
                    <label for="Subject">Subject of Email: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="subject" placeholder="Enter the subject of your Email">
                <div class="form-group" id="message">
                    <label for="message">Message: </label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">


                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript can't do email and there's no way of sending info to email directly by html.
You can use PHP at backend.

For this segment of code you are showing, try with

As for details, please refer to:

https://html.form.guide/email-form/html-email-form.html

Comment: I have done a lot of email sending with Javascript / NodeJS - but you point is well taken.

Comment: @Nelles fair enough haha, thank you for your advice